# Starting a GIS project in java with OSM data

Tags: open-source-gis, openstreetmap, java, viewer

I am starting a new GIS project in Java. Till now, I used JTS and geotools to load shape files - these data were then displayed on a swing interface. For this new project, I would like to use OSM data. I am wondering what is the most efficient way to start.

What I am dreaming on is a simple and light open source java viewer that would be able to load and display OSM data in both vector and raster format, and that I could extend for my project.

Does it exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use a all-Java web mapping framework, you may want to take a look at Geomajas. It has a plug-in to display OpenStreetMap raster data. If you want to odisplay the vector data as well, then you first have to download that and store it in a database (Postgis is a good choice). This can then be accessed either using the Geotools or the Hibernate layer.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell, Geotools can not handle OSM data natively, but you could [add the data to Postgis](http://blog.geoserver.org/2009/01/30/geoserver-and-openstreetmap/).  Geotools as well as other mapping api's should have the ability to interact with PostGIS.  Another option is to set up [Geoserver](http://geoserver.org/display/GEOS/Welcome) and add a wms layer to your app.

Finally one option is to [use openmap and write your own layer](http://openmap.bbn.com/mailArchives/openmap-users/2010-05/6444.html).  You may also be able to [do this with Geotools](http://svn.geotools.org/tags/2.5-M2/modules/unsupported/coverageio/src/main/java/org/geotools/image/io/mosaic/TileManager.java).

Comment: If you want to write an OSM datastore for GeoTools then you may want to start with http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GEOTDOC/Old+Creating+a+DataStore+Tutorial (I can't find a "new" one). Ask on the devel list for more help.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you are familiar with JOSM, the Java-based OSM editor.  If not, you may want to check it out.

All code is licensed under GPL2 or GPL3.