# looking for open source Java SE map viewer library that work with osm files or osm pre-downloaded tiles

Tags: openstreetmap, java

I am new here and I hope I can find answers to my question here! I am developing a mapping platform for desktop, web, mobile (Android). I finally finished embedding mapping into my android software using osmdroid library. Now I want to start Java desktop part and I want to know is there any open source library like osmdroid or mapsforge for Java SE?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Related question: http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/2158/162

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mapsforge works on Android with Java.  This is the [GETTING STARTED GUIDE](http://code.google.com/p/mapsforge/wiki/GettingStartedMapView) with sample applications (that are a real pain in the neck to set up and are easier to work from Honeycomb onwards).

Answer (score 3):

While it's not a library, take a look at [JOSM](http://josm.openstreetmap.de/), which is a Java editor for OpenStreetMap data. It uses [MapCSS](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/MapCSS) for styling vector layers, and has a JMapViewer component for tiled raster layers.

Comment: definitely one solution.  how much support does it get compared to other solutions?

Comment: I can't say about other solutions, but JOSM has several developers working on it with regular releases (monthly).